# Create a pivot table using a macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Question) I am recording a macro to create a pivot table, When I am running the macro with a new workbook it gives me Invalid procedure call or argument. I think in Tabledestination the code is picking up the previous file name which is creating this error. I have tried to put new workbook name as a variable in a code. It is still not working. Please someone can help with this. Below is the code.

```
  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table1", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="5list!R12C18", _
        TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=8
```

I have tried to put new workbook name as a variable in a code. It is still not working.

Comment: I think there must be two things which exist in the workbook (whatever workbook) before running the sub : 1. A named range "Table1" workbook scope. 2. A sheet with name "5list". So, maybe you need to check that first.

Comment: Title needs just the first character to be capitalized.